# How to join a list of dictionaries by dict val. Jinja2

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2

I'm working on a backend flask/jinja2 app and I know how to join a list of strings; however,
I need to join a list of dictionaries. I want to join all the dictionaries values, which are strings, into one string... I'm not quite sure of the syntax in Jinja2 for this. an example of the dict is below.

```
[{key:'value'},{key:'secondValue'}]
```

with an expected output of

```
"value, secondValue"
```

Comment: Do all the dictionaries have the same key? Do you know this key upfront, or do you want to join the values of _all_ keys in the dictionaries?

Comment: I want to join the values of all keys in this dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```py
{{iterable_object|map(attribute)|join(',')}}
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Could you please explain your answer? A few more comments might come in handy for those new to Jinja2! Also, I recommend that you put any piece of code inside the [backticks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268394/how-do-i-put-a-backtick-in-backticks-to-make-it-appear-as-code) to improve readability!